# Install .apk files placed inside assets folder without copying it to sdcard

Tags: android, eclipse

I've created an app in Eclipse and I've placed some other `.apk` files inside the assets folder of this app. I've added some image buttons and onClick I want to install the `.apk` app placed inside assets folder without copying it to external sdcard. I'm trying the following code but I'm getting the Parse Error. Here is the code:

```
ImageButton animal1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
animal1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open("Animal Game.apk");
        out = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.mypack.myproj/Animal Game.apk");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile("/data/data/com.mypack.myproj/files/Animal Game.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        startActivity(intent);
    } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     }
});
```

The error I'm getting is Parse Error:

> There was a problem parsing the package.

Please anyone help me out to solve this error

Comment: Yes, it can't parse your APK. So, is your APK valid?

Comment: Ya my `APK` is valid, and its `AIR application` I've already installed this `APK` on my device.. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You must copy your apk file to the SD Card before passing it to the PackageManager, as the PackageManager runs in a separate process as an independent app, and cannot access your app's internal files.

Comment: what if there in no sdcard in the device...?

Comment: @Sush19 Then either copy it to a world readable part of the internal storage, or ask the user to insert one.